# Replace or Remove a character from a string

Tags: vb.net

I have Textbox1.Text = `12343780.343435467`

Expected Output: > I want to replace "." and "0" with nothing.

```
1234378343435467
```

Code:

```
Dim myString As String = TextBox1.Text
myString.Replace(".", String.Empty)
myString.Replace("0", String.Empty)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. When you call Replace, the original string is not changed but a new string is returned with the changes requested

Comment: Ok, i think understand, Thanks worked :)